# subpad returns NULL

Tags: c, ncurses

I stuck on following trouble with ncurses: when I try to create subpad on main screen, I receive NULL pointer as result and `errno` = 0.

Test example:

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main(int, char**) {
    initscr();

    WINDOW *pad = subpad(stdscr, 10, 10, 6, 1);
    assert(pad);
    delwin(pad);

    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

Compile it with:

```
$ g++ -g -O0 -o pad ./main.cpp -lncurses
```

Just before assertion fires I have following state:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/ncurses/pad 

Breakpoint 1, main () at ./main.cpp:10
10      assert(pad);
(gdb) p pad
$1 = (WINDOW *) 0x0
(gdb) p errno
$2 = 0
(gdb)
```

[Man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/subpad) says that NULL may be returned only with `errno = ENOMEM`.

I use Debian Jessie 64bit, gcc 4.9, libncurses 5.9.

My question is: what I'm doing wrong and why I get NULL pointer instead of supbad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

subpad() expects a parent pad as the first argument, not a WINDOW (stdscr) although references to windows and pads are stored in a WINDOW* there are in fact some difference between them (pads lack screen coordinates and cannot be refreshed with wrefresh).

From manpages:

> "A pad is like a window, except that it is not restricted by the
>   screen size, and is not necessarily associated with a particular part
>   of the screen."

So you should create the parent pad first:

```
WINDOW *ppad, *subpad;

ppad = newpad(50,50);
if (ppad == NULL) {
    /* always check for null */
}

/* create the subpad */
subpad = subpad(ppad, lines, cols, y, x);
if(subpad == NULL ) {
    /* always check for null */
}   

addstr("Subpad created\n");
refresh();

/* just a pause... */
getch();
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I'm newbie in ncurses. Have I understood right it's impossible to create subpad in window and I have to use `subwin` for this purpose?

Comment: Exactly. Subpads are not a "visual component". It's only used as a "virtual" window to put content in them for later copy&paste in the stdscr. 
A subwindow is probably what you want and you can use stdscr (or any other WINDOW) as the parent when you create one with subwin